# MySQL Event to add booking on stored day and time

Tags: mysql, events

I'm creating a booking system and one of the requirements is for a mass 'Regular' booking to be added automatically.

I believe an easy solution to this would be to store all members 'regular' days in a table, then have a scheduled event that retrieves all the records and inserts each row as a record in the bookings table.

```
 Regulars Table

|id  | memberid  | time  |  day  |  group  |
____________________________________________
| 1  | 42        | 08:00 | Monday|  2      |
| 2  | 42        | 08:00 | Friday|  1      |
| 3  | 25        | 11:00 | Friday|  1      |
____________________________________________
```

As the days are stored as VARCHAR textual, i need a way to generate the next day as y/m/d. In PHP this would be date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next tuesday'));

So i'd like to know what the correct way to achieve the following:

for each row returned
insert into bookings (memberid,time,date,group) values (row[memberid], row[time], the next row[day], row[group]

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you the next week day:

```
select id,
       memberid,
       t.time,
       date_add(curdate(), 
                interval 6 + 
                FIND_IN_SET(t.day,'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday') 
                - weekday(curdate()) day) as nextWeekDay
       ,t.group         
from T
```

<kbd>[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db2ed/3)</kbd>

Comment: The following resulted in the error: select id,
       memberid,
       regularclasses.time,
       date_add(curdate(), 
                interval 6 + 
                FIND_IN_SET(t.day,'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday') 
                - weekday(curdate()) regularclasses.day) as nextWeekDay
       ,regularclasses.groupnumber         
from regularclasses  |||||   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regularclasses.day) as nextWeekDay ,regularclasses.groupnumber f at line7

Comment: Change `egularclasses.day` before `as nextweekDay` to the `day`. It's not the DAY field from your table, it is the `DAY` MYSQL key word used in the [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function. It's an example of why you shouldn't use keywords as a table/fields names (time,day,...) - it can be sometimes confusing.